# The appearance of volume $V$ in the Fourier series representation of a periodic cubic system

Tags: electrostatics, potential, fourier-transform, boundary-conditions, volume

In the textbook [*Understanding Molecular Simulation* by Frenkel and Smit (Second Edition)](http://books.google.com/books?id=5qTzldS9ROIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=understanding%20molecular%20simulation&source=bl&ots=nEOLYn-bYo&sig=Z6CxOQEs6giRdButwf0sR4pJSss&hl=en&sa=X&ei=N9EjUOybK-fl0QHKr4CoBA&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=understanding%20molecular%20simulation&f=false), the authors represent a function $f(\textbf{r})$ (which depends on the coordinates of a periodic system) as a Fourier series.  I quote from page 295 of the text:

> Let us consider a periodic system with a cubic box of length $L$ and volume $V$.  Any function $f(\textbf{r})$ that depends on the coordinates of our system can be represented by a Fourier series:
>
> $$f(\textbf{r}) = \frac{1}{V} \sum_{\boldsymbol{\ell} = -\infty}^{\infty} \tilde{f}(\textbf{k}) e^{i \textbf{k} \cdot \textbf{r}} \; \; \; \; \textbf{(12.1.6)}$$
>
> where $\textbf{k} = \frac{2\pi}{L}\boldsymbol{\ell}$ with $\boldsymbol{\ell} = (\ell_x, \ell_y, \ell_z)$ are the lattice vectors in Fourier space.  The Fourier coefficients $\tilde{f}(\textbf{k})$ are calculated using
>
> $$\tilde{f}(\textbf{k}) = \int_V d\textbf{r} \; f(\textbf{r}) e^{-i\textbf{k} \cdot \textbf{r}} \; \; \; \; \textbf{(12.1.7)}$$

Now, the authors use equation **(12.1.6)** to write the electric potential $\phi(\textbf{r})$ in Fourier space:

$$\phi(\textbf{r}) = \frac{1}{V} \sum_{\textbf{k}} \tilde{\phi}(\textbf{k}) e^{i\textbf{k} \cdot \textbf{r}}$$

The authors write:

> In Fourier space, Poisson's equation has a much simpler form.  We can write for the Poisson equation:
>
> $$-\nabla^2 \phi(\textbf{r}) = -\nabla^2 \left( \frac{1}{V} \sum_{\textbf{k}} \tilde{\phi}(\textbf{k}) e^{i\textbf{k} \cdot \textbf{r}} \right) = \frac{1}{V} \sum_{\textbf{k}} k^2 \tilde{\phi}(\textbf{k}) e^{i\textbf{k} \cdot \textbf{r}} \; \; \; \; \textbf{(12.1.8)}$$

My question is, why is the $\frac{1}{V}$ factor present in equations **(12.1.6)** and **(12.1.8)**?  What is the significance of the $\frac{1}{V}$ factor in $\phi(\textbf{r}) = \frac{1}{V} \sum_{\textbf{k}} \tilde{\phi}(\textbf{k}) e^{i\textbf{k} \cdot \textbf{r}}$?

In contrast, [the article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Exponential_Fourier_series) does not include this prefactor.  I realize that that article is dealing with the general case, whereas here we are considering a system with a cubic box of volume $V$.  But shouldn't the units of $\phi(\textbf{r})$ be the same as those of $\tilde{\phi}(\textbf{k})$?  The $\frac{1}{V}$ seems to preclude $\phi(\textbf{r})$ and $\tilde{\phi}(\textbf{k})$ having the same units.

Do you have any advice?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I) Let us just consider $1$ dimension for simplicity. (The generalization to higher dimensions is straightforward). Then the volume factor $V$ is just a length factor $L$.

II) The standard Fourier series formulas can be derived from $(12.1.7)$ and $(12.1.6)$ by taken the length $L$ to be $L=2\pi$. Then $(12.1.7)$ and $(12.1.6)$ become the standard Fourier series formulas

$$\tag{12.1.7'}   c_{n} ~=~  \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \! dx~ f(x) e^{-in x}, $$
$$\tag{12.1.6'}  f(x)~=~\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} c_n~e^{in x}
~=~f(x+2\pi), $$

via the identifications

$$\ell~=~ n~\in~\mathbb{Z}, \qquad \tilde{f}(\ell) ~=~2\pi c_{n} . $$

III) Going back to $3$ dimensions, the $1/V$ normalization in $(12.1.6)$ is important. Of course, in another convention, it could be put in $(12.1.7)$ instead, or alternatively, symmetrically as $1/\sqrt{V}$ in both formulas $(12.1.6)$ and $(12.1.7)$.

Comment: Thanks.  But, given the $1/V$ normalization, what are the units of $\tilde{\phi}(\textbf{k})$ with respect to those of $\phi(\textbf{r})$ in the equation $$\phi(\textbf{r}) = \frac{1}{V} \sum_{\textbf{k}} \tilde{\phi}(\textbf{k}) e^{i\textbf{k}\cdot\textbf{r}}$$?

Comment: $[\tilde{f}]= [V] [f]= [L]^3 [f]$, cf. eq. $(12.1.7)$, or eq. $(12.1.6)$.

Answer (score 2):

The usual Fourier series formula states that a function $g(x)$ with period $2\pi$ can be expressed as

$$  g(x) = \sum_{k\in {\mathbb Z}} c_k \, e^{ikx}$$

where $c_n$ (the coefficients of the Fourier series) are given by

$$c_k = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} g(x) \, e^{-i  x \, k}dx$$

If we have $f(x)$ with period $L$, we can relate with the above by $f(x) = g(2 \pi x/L)$, so we get the equivalent formulas:

$$  f(x) = \sum_{k\in {\mathbb Z}} c_k \, e^{i k x}$$

$$c_k = \frac{1}{L} \int_{0}^{L} f(x) \, e^{-i  x \, k}dx$$

One can, alternatively move the normalization factor $1/L$ to the first equation. It's just a matter a convention.

The extension to 3 dimensions is straightforward.